# Haskell: Signature/type mess in a simple calculation

Tags: haskell

I am very much new to Haskell and trying to learn the beast.
here is a simple function that translates time in seconds to [days,hours,minutes,seconds].
I've been struggling half a day with the signature and types and I still get a type error.
It looks like I've tried all kind of signature combination  - no luck. Could you please help.

1. What signature do I need? I tried the `secToTime :: Integer -> [Integer]` first and got bunch of type errors that are cryptic enough to confuse the hell out of me.
2. Would it be the correct way to display the resulting list: `main = do print secToTime` or `main = do map (\x -> putStrLn . show) secToTime`?

   ```
   secToTime secs = [d,h,m,s]
     where s = secs `rem` 60
           m = truncate(secs / 60) `rem` 60
           h = truncate(secs / 3600) `rem` 24
           d = truncate(secs / 86400)
   ```

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The issue is that you are mixing `rem`, which works with `Integral`s and `/` which works with `Fractional`s. And easy fix would be to use `div` in place of `/`. This also means `truncate` is not needed because `div` represents integer division.

Basically, Haskell differentiates types that act like integers from other types. Any type in the `Integral` typeclass acts like an integer--these include `Int`, `Integer` and a ton of more specialized types like `Word`. For your particular code, you want to treat all the numbers like integers, so you should use functions with a type like `Integral a => a -> a -> a`, like `div` rather than `/`.

Another note: since your time representation *always* has four fields, you should *not* use a list. You can instead use a tuple `(d,h,m,s)` or create your own type:

```
data Time = Time Integer Integer Integer Integer deriving (Show, Eq)
```

The `deriving (Show, Eq)` bit just gives you `show` and `==` for the `Time` type for free.

So, putting all this together, we get this function:

```
secToTime secs = Time d h m s
  where s = secs `rem` 60
        m = secs `div` 60 `rem` 60
        h = secs `div` 3600 `rem` 24
        d = secs `div` 86400
```

So now the natural question is, what sort of type signature does this have? It is actually very simple:

```
secToTime :: Integer -> Time
```

Note how this makes it *very* obvious what the returned data represents!

Since `Time` derived `Show`, we can just use `print` on it. So we could have:

```
main = print $ secToTime 12345
```

This works because, internally, `print` just calls `show` followed by outputting the result. Since `Time` is an instance of `Show`, it has a `show` function defined and so can be used with `print`.

Running this program will print:

```
Time 0 3 25 45
```

However, this is not really an ideal result! The format it got printed in is awkward. Instead, let's first get rid of the derived `Show`:

```
data Time = Time Integer Integer Integer Integer deriving (Eq)
```

and write our own. Fun!

```
instance Show Time where 
  show (Time d h m s) = show d ++ " days " ++ 
                        show h ++ " hours " ++ 
                        show m ++ " minutes " ++ 
                        show s ++ " seconds"
```

Now, when we run `main`, we get this output:

```
0 days 3 hours 25 minutes 45 seconds
```

It's much better. Basically, all we did was tell Haskell how `Time`s should look as `String`s by specifying the `Show` instance and defining a `show` function.

Given that you have a `Time` type, you can extract the values from it using pattern matching:

```
timeToSec (Time d h m s) = d * 86400 + h * 3600 + m * 60 + s
```

The pattern `(Time d h m s)` takes your `Time` value and deconstructs it back into the four integers it contains, naming them `d`, `h`, `m` and `s`. This lets you write arbitrary functions that can operate on `Time`s by getting the actual numbers out.

Comment: Thank you very much! Ah, those little things ... I like the new type advise -  good for learning. I don't seem to be able to print it from main though. It complains that "No instance for show (Show(Integer->Time)). I just do simple: "main = print secToTime"

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry, I posted the follow up question before I saw your answer on how to display it.

Comment: Creating the instance of Show Time is nice but I might want to format the output in different ways later on. What if I wanted to leave the formatting for later time? How would I extract Integers from Time type for further formatting/processing?

Comment: For reference, `print secToTime` tries to print the *function* `secToTime`. To actually print a time value, you'd need to supply `secToTime` an argument. I'll address your later question by editing the answer.

Comment: I suggest a type with named fields, `data Time = Time { days, hours, minutes, seconds :: Integer }`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: That's definitely a good idea. I had considered it, but decided a simpler `Time` type would save some explaining and be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

As far as printing is concerned,

```
main = print $ secToTime 1234
```

should work (since there is only one statement, you don't need a do).  Notice that you either need a `$` where I put it or you need to surround `secToTime` and its argument with parentheses.  `print secToTime` by itself is a type error because functions cannot be printed, and `print secToTime 1234` is doubly a type error - first, Haskell applies `print` to `secToTime`, producing a type error as detailed above, then (pretending that it is possible to print `secToTime`), Haskell will apply the `IO ()` that results from a call to `print` and apply it to `1234`, which is complete nonsense since a `IO ()` is not a function.

The parentheses cause `secToTime` to be applied to `1234` first, and then the resulting list will be passed to `print`.  The `$` basically does the same thing - it is a normal function that takes its right argument and passes it to its left argument.  Since operators bind lower than normal functions, `secToTime` is applied first, causing everything to work well.

Answer (score 1):

While I totally agree that Tikhon's solution is the best for this special case, let me show you how you could generate list from seconds in a general way:

```
secToTime secs = let mods = [24,60,60]
                     (d:rest) = scanr (flip div) secs mods
                 in d: zipWith mod rest mods
```

Comment: Looks very ... different :) I am at such a learning phase that does not allow me to fully understand/appreciate the above. Although I'd be very interested to learn if you could explain what's happening in your function.  Thanks.